# Пытаюсь создать исполняемый JAR-файл, но не получается

Tags: java, gradle, jar

[image: Скриншот]

Выдаёт ошибку:

> Caching disabled for task ':jar' because:
> Build cache is disabled

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120).  Приведите содержимое вашего `build.gradle` файла и укажите существенные детали конфигурации вашей среды (хотя бы версии JDK и Gradle).  Кроме того, если вы получили ответ(ы) на свой [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1568956/), следует выбрать, какой из ответов помог решить вашу проблему и принять его, поставив зеленую галочку.

Answer (score 0):

Включите кэширование в своём инструменте сборки для создания JAR файла. Судя по ошибке, оно отключено.